# Does iOS coerce NSStrings into NSNumbers?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Subtitle: why does this code work?  It seems to allow comparison of `NSNumber` with `NSString` types via some sort of coercion.  I'm trying to compare a selection from a `UISegmentedControl` with a previously stored value.

```
- (IBAction)minSegmentedControlChanged:(id)sender // MINIMUM value
{
UISegmentedControl *s1 = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

NSMutableArray *pD = [[GameData gameData].curData valueForKey:@"persData"];

// Must make sure max >= min

NSNumber *currMax = [pD objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@", [currMax class]); // __NSCFString ?!

int ss1 = s1.selectedSegmentIndex;
NSNumber *SS1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ss1 + 2];

if (SS1 >= currMax) SS1 = currMax;

NSLog(@"%@", SS1); // Answer is correct, appears to be an integer
NSLog(@"%@", [SS1 class]); // __NSCFString ?!

[pD replaceObjectAtIndex:0
              withObject:SS1];
[[GameData gameData].curData setObject:pD
                                forKey:@"persData"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[GameData gameData].curData valueForKey:@"persData"]);

}
```

I am particularly asking about:

```
NSNumber *currMax = [pD objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@", [currMax class]); // __NSCFString ?!
```

which seems to return a string for a number.  `[[GameData gameData].curData valueForKey:@"persData"];` is initialized as follows:

```
         _persData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2", @"8", @"TWL", @"0", @"0", nil];
```

which is a string at element 1.  So why can I ask it for an `NSNumber`, which reports that it is actually a `__NSCFString` on which I can do arithmetic comparisons on?  I've only been at objective-c for a few months but this seems strange.

Comment: It took you a few months to figure out that objective-c was strange? :)

Comment: For one thing--`%@` prints a string, not an integer.  I'd be curious to see how the statements you're pointing out print if you tell them to print as integers, using `%i`.

Comment: Came from `R`, so it was all strange for a long time.  When you think you know it, something like this comes along.  Unless, of course, it's "obvious".

Comment: @WendiKidd if I change `NSLog(@"%@", SS1);` to `NSLog(@"%i", SS1);` Xcode warns before building that I'm trying to write `NSNumber` as `int`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `currMax` isn't necessarily an `NSNumber` just because you declared it as such. Perhaps this can be best demonstrated by using a type of `id`. This should highlight that the type specifier is just a hint to you (and the compiler)

Comment: @BryanHanson: `@"Something inside"` is a `NSString`, no matter what is inside, even if it is some digits `@"34"`, `@"4.5"`.

Comment: Right, I am aware of that, which is what leads to some type conversions.

Comment: @SedateAlien makes a good point.  Also, seems like you've got a good answer now. But for future reference, you're getting that warning because you can't print NSNumbers straight out--try this instead: `NSLog(@"$i, [SS1 intValue]);`  You have to convert NSNumbers to integers with the `intValue` method before printing them like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, let's walk through this one step at a time.

First of all, all of the elements in `_persData` are strings. Period. `NSString` is a class cluster, so the concrete classes of the various instances you inquire about may look weird, but that's to support toll-free bridging and other magic that's not relevant to this discussion.

```
NSNumber *currMax = [pD objectAtIndex:1];
```

This line is incorrect. You might think there's some sort of coercion going on, but actually you're just assigning an `NSString *` to an `NSNumber *`. Which is wrong, and will explode in your face at the earliest convenience. It so happens that `objectAtIndex:` returns an `id`, which is stripped of type information, so the compiler is trusting you to store it in the right kind of pointer, but that's not enforced until you try to send a message to it.

```
if (SS1 >= currMax) SS1 = currMax;
```

This is an extremely wily comparison. `SS1` is most certainly an `NSNumber`, but `currMax` is an `NSString`. But we're not comparing the values of those objects. To do that, we'd use the `compare:` method. Instead, we're comparing them as pointers, looking only at their addresses in memory. By some accident of implementation, `SS1` seems to always reside at a higher address than `currMax`.

If all of the foregoing is true, then `SS1` is always of type `NSString` after the above line is executed, which explains why this line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [SS1 class]);
```

Always indicates that `SS1` is a string.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation.  I think I know how to repair it now, and have a better (not perfect) understanding.

Comment: @JakeKing I totally agree, right now I have egg on my face but at least it's not shrapnel!  I am skilled in the art of lame-ass coding!

Comment: I'm rather fascinated by the fact that so much of `objective-c` is totally neurotic about types and strict object orientation but in the case of `objectAtIndex` it plays fast and loose.  I'm going to have to meditate on this.

Comment: Think about it like this. There's no such thing as a strongly type-safe container in Objective-C, so `NSArray` only knows that it stores things that are of type `NSObject`. There's no compile-time check that can be done to ensure the objects you're getting out of a container are of a particular subtype, so that's on you. This is actually true in more places than you'd suspect, since Objective-C type semantics are actually based on the messages an object responds to. All the stuff that looks like static type-checking is for your protection, but the veil is thinner in some places than others.

Comment: @warrenm So even if I init `_persData` with specific data types in each position I still have to use them properly (sounds so reasonable now!), right?  Even if `Objective-c` is loosing track of the type the thing is still of that type - does that sound reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

You actually initialize the `NSMutableArray` with `NSString`, not number.

When you pull object out of `NSMutableArray` with `objectAtIndex`, the return type of the function is `id`, which it will blindly cast to `NSNumber`, while the actual object is `NSString`.

It seems that the `SS1 >= currMax` statement is comparing the addresses of the objects instead of their values.

You can test it out with this snippet of code:

```
NSNumber *a = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt: 34];
NSNumber *b = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt: 3];

NSNumber *c = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt: 34];
NSNumber *d = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt: 234];

NSLog(@"%p %p %p %p %d %d", a, b, c, d, a >= b, c >= d);
```

Comment: Right, I initialized it as a string.  Your 2nd sentence unsettles me a bit.  If I can't put it in an array as a certain type and get it back out as the same type, what can I trust?

Comment: @BryanHanson You'll still get an `NSString` object from the array, but Objective-C is weakly typed, so you can place that into any variable you want, since the return type is `id` (aka it returns any type of object).

Comment: @JakeKing Thanks, this is a subtlety I obviously had not appreciated.